# Key Error in a class based DetailView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, keyerror

I've had this problem a few times before but I've always been able to work it out. This time I cant. Its just returning:

"Key error at streams/**sport_slug** 
'pk'
"

The error at at line 34 in the Views, which I have highlighted below:

Views.py:

```
class StreamSport(ListView):
    template_name = "stream/stream-index.html"
    context_object_name = 'stream_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.sport = get_object_or_404(Sport, sport_slug=self.kwargs['sport_slug'])
        *self.pk = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])*
        return Video.objects.filter(sport=self.sport, pk=self.pk)
```

URLs.py:

```
app_name = 'streams'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', StreamIndex.as_view(), name='stream-index'),
    path('<slug:sport_slug>/', StreamSport.as_view(), name='stream-sport'),
    path('<slug:sport_slug>/<int:pk>/', StreamDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

stream-index.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'streams:detail' video.sport.sport_slug video.pk %}"
```

Edit: As Lemayzeur I got myself confused. The key error was caused by an attempt at fixing another error. I thought I made progress when instead I was moving backwards. The original error, and the one I am back to now is a "Reverse for 'detail' with arguments" error.

To clarify, what I am trying to do is build a ListView that lists out all the videos in a model, then link each of those videos to its own Details page. Its the DetailView itself thats giving me some issue:

```
class StreamDetail(DetailView):
    model = Video
    template_name = 'stream/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.sport = get_object_or_404(Sport, sport_slug=self.kwargs['sport_slug'])
        self.pk = Video.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Video.objects.filter(sport=self.sport, pk=self.pk)
```

This is the error it is giving me:

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['stream\\/(?P<sport_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

The traceback itself is extremely unhelpful and it just pointing to the bootstrapcdn in the basefile.

stream-index.html:

```
{% for video in stream_list %}
  <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;margin-left: 2rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{video.headline_image.url}}" alt="Card image cap" style="width: 20rem;">
            <div class="card-body" style="width: 18rem;">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'streams:detail' video.id %}">{{video.name}}</a></h5>
              <p class="card-text" style="width: 18rem;">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <a href="{% url 'streams:detail' video.sport.sport_slug video.pk %}" class="btn btn-success">Watch Now</a>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this url `'streams:detail'` calls `StreamDetail` not `StreamSport`. so you don't have access to `self.kwargs` in that view

Comment: I realised just before you posted your reply. I've made an edit to my original question.

Comment: so what's the error now? the traceback ?

Comment: The error is: 

Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['stream\\/(?P<sport_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

The traceback itself is unhelpful. Its pointing to something I know isnt the problem in the base.html file. I've removed it before and it still said it was the problem, so I think its just a weird bug

Comment: can you post how loop through Video List.... `stream-index.html`

Comment: Just added to the original post for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you show in the full snippet, in your template you are only passing `video.id` to the url tag, whereas the detail URL requires id and slug. Make sure you pass them both:

```
<a href="{% url 'streams:detail' video.sport.sport_slug video.id %}">
```

Comment: That is the dumbest thing I've ever overlooked. I copied it for testing reasons on another page I was using and never gave it a second thought. Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the url that you have posted:
Check this line

instead of

```
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'streams:detail' video.id %}">{{video.name}}</a></h5>
```

it should be

```
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'streams:detail' video.sport.sport_slug video.pk %}">{{video.name}}</a></h5>
```